# How can I install or work with Ubuntu core? Are there any other cores?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, coreos

This is a ported [Ubuntu core](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Core_with_Qt-Embedded) for an arm-based computer board(Nanopi m1):

I did write it on SD card, but there is nothing to do with this. No terminal, no options!

How can I install something upon this?

Are there any other cores? Is it hard to make another Linux ported for this board?

Comment: why did you remove the link :-?

Comment: I found the solution here : http://superuser.com/questions/1174358/how-to-install-something-on-ubuntu-core with using ssh protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is by @PuTTY at superuser:

Connect your `NanoPI` board to your local network (plug Ethernet port of NanoPI to the LAN port on your router), wait at least a minute to get time `NanoPi` to start then use [AngryIP scanner](http://angryip.org/) to find IP address of `NanoPI`. If you use unix based operation system, use terminal/console to connect to your NanoPI by issue following command:

```
ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Where xx.xx.xx.xx is IP address you found with [AngryIP scanner](http://angryip.org/).

Default password  for *Ubuntu_Core_with_Qt-Embedded* might be `fa` (check documentation regarding `ssh` password it could be changed since I tried it last time)

If computer you trying to connect from is Windows based operation system, you may use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) terminal as SSH client.